# Adding two numbers together mixed with comma from two textbox and automatically gives out results on the third textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to add two numbers mixed with comma together e.g. (30,000 + 23,000) etc.. but i couldn't find a reasonable solution to it, i have search everywhere online to get a like-some solution but all to no avail. so any help from u guys will be very much appreciated..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>comma</title>

  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery.min.js')?>"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Comma(Num) {
      Num += '';
      Num = Num.replace(',', '');
      Num = Num.replace(',', '');
      Num = Num.replace(',', '');
      Num = Num.replace(',', '');
      Num = Num.replace(',', '');
      Num = Num.replace(',', '');
      x = Num.split('.');
      x1 = x[0];
      x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
      var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (rgx.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
      return x1 + x2;
    }

    function sumCalc() {

      var tb1 = parseFloat(document.getElementByid('txt1').val.replace(/,/g, ""));

      var tb2 = parseFloat(document.getElementByid('txt2').val.replace(/,/g, ""));
      var tb3 = parseFloat(document.getElementByid('txt3').val.replace(/,/g, ""));

      tb3.val(tb1 + tb2);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <label>Text 1<span>*</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" id="txt1" name="txt1">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <label>Text 2<span>*</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" id="txt2" name="txt2">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <label>Text 3<span>*</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" onfocus="javascript:sumCalc();" id="txt3" name="txt3">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You just want to convert two strings to numbers and add them?

Comment: Is the repeated `Num = Num.replace(',', '');` a typo?

Comment: @freedomn-m I agree, but then look at `sumCalc()`

Comment: @freedomn-m Odd question is odd.  I don't think the OP knows they have the answer already.

Comment: Voted close: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. ** - your code does not reproduce the problem as it doesn't run due to very basic issues (eg `parseFloat(..).val()`).  Have a read of [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

this will be your possible solution. i just modify your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>comma</title>

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery.min.js')?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Comma(Num) {
  Num += '';
  Num = Num.replace(',', '');
  x = Num.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1))
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  return x1 + x2;
}

function sumCalc() {

  var tb1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txt1').value.replace(/,/g, ""));
  console.log(tb1)
  var tb2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txt2').value.replace(/,/g, ""));
  var tb3 = document.getElementById('txt3');

  tb3.value=(tb1 + tb2);
  tb3.value=Comma(tb3.value);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <form>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 1<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" id="txt1" name="txt1">
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 2<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" id="txt2" name="txt2">
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <label>Text 3<span>*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" onfocus="javascript:sumCalc();" id="txt3" name="txt3">
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```